# Architecture/Implementation of authentication with local and remote data

Tags: android, ios, architecture, synchronization, client-server

I'm developing a game in which users can start playing anonymously offline. Whenever they want, they can authenticate through facebook, and are allowed to post their scores to leaderboards and play challenges. It looks pretty simple. It is not!

Now I encountered a architectural problem I was not expecting, and I'm asking if there is already a standard way to solve it.

Assumptions:
Users store their personal score locally, until they authenticate.
When they are connected, an online service stores the score online.
The device and the server should be synchronized so that the user maintains as much as possible the score through different devices, and the server can use his score to match making and leaderboards.

Now, what happens if:

1. a player that authenticated before, plays offline? The new score will be synchronized at the first connection client => server.
2. a player changes facebook profile. The score is stored locally, so the new user plays with the old score, and when the user connects to the service, according to 1, the synchronization client => server pushes player 1's score to the new player. WRONG!
3. a player maintains the same facebook profile, but changes device. The score on the new device is 0, so the synchronization should be server => client instead of client => server. Also, whenever he comes back to the previous device, the synchronization should be server => client instead of client => server.

There are a lot of other problems that arise, actually, combining these three aspects: changing user, changing device, playing offline.

Thinking at a possible solution I thought at possible checks performed on the fb id, on the score, on a simple numeric counter or on the save date, both locally and remotely, but no solution is complete and there always conditions in which the player could lose their score or a new player could get a score of a stronger player.

Is there some algorithm, best practice, architecture, or whatever that could help me with this (strange) problem?

Comment: not a solution but have you considered [leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards)?

Comment: Trying to get the question simple I omitted the fact that the FB authentication is matched with GameSparks' authentication to provide leaderboards and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I came to a partial conclusion, that maybe will be better completed later on.

Together with the score I store the FBid and a serial number. To cover the most common situation **we need both**.

This is a initial scheme of what I think that the synchronization procedure needs to be:

```
 public void Sync()
{
if (local.FBid == null)
    // there's no FBid stored locally, so it's the first connection to
    // an online profile from this device.
    // The user might have used his profile before, so we cannot trust
    // a simple client-> server sync that would wipe the online score.
    // On the other hand, the user could have played a lot offline and
    // now decided to finally go online and export his score, that would
    // be lost with a server -> client sync.
    // To decide which profile is better we must trust the serial, considering
    // that a empty profile has serial 0.
    // We must understand if there is already a online profile.
    // If there is not, create it, otherwise take the one with the highest serial.
    // To do that we initialize and simply fall in the successive case.
{
    local.FBid = used.FBid;
}

if (local.FBid == used.FBid)
    // the local user is the same as the online user, we have to check if the player has advanced
    // the score playing offline. In that case the server will be updated.
    // Instead if the player is on a new device or increased the score using a different device,
    // the client will be updated.
    // there's no way to guarantee coherence if the player uses two devices on the same time, obviously.
{
    if (local.serial > server.serial) // supposing that a non-existant profile has serial == 0
        SyncClientToServer(); // update or create
    else
        SyncServerToClient();

} else // if (local.FBid != used.FBid)
    // the local stored user is not the same that has been used for the authentication.
    // the player is asked two options:
    // 1. wipe the local score and get the currently authenticated user from the server (that may be empty)
    // 2. keep the local score as it is, but play offline (without any sync) until the correct authentication is done
{
    if (AskWipeData())
        SyncServerToClient();
    else
        logoff(); // allow user to change the profile or go on playing offline
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but a behaviour I observed while playing games which uses google play games services to synchronize data.

These games prompt me with a dialogue when I play offline for a while from a different device and goes online.

This dialogue tells me that there is a different profile available on the server and do I want to load that profile(saved state) or continue with the current profile.

1. if I select to continue with current profile my current profile gets uploaded on the server and previous profile is lost.
2. if I select to load profile from server my current profile is lost and my game gets synced with the server.

Additionally I also loose any saved profile if I change my google account.(previously synced profile is still available on earlier account)

This is not a perfect solution, but it works and gives the user a choice on how to deal with his/her game data.

Also to be noted, any solution can not be perfect considering user can use multiple devices with unstable connectivity.

Comment: Uhm... what if I have a strong player on the new device, so locally there's a stronger stored profile... I play and then connect with another player? I can answer "yes" and the stronger player profile is pasted on the weaker one...
One solution could be to store in the profile also the FB id. The new user will play with the stronger profile but could not save it to the new FB id.

Comment: yes that is what will happen but only until local profile is not associated with any account, once it's associated with any account for the first time it can not be transferred.